# Why can't I break from this get requests loop?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm web scraping and while I run the code, the requests keep going even though I've specified it to break when it reached 72. Help?

I've tried adding a print(variable) function and it didn't work either.

```
# Redeclaring the lists to store data in
names = []
years = []
imdb_ratings = []
metascores = []
votes = []

# Preparing the monitoring of the loop
start_time = time.time()
requests = 0

# For every year in the interval 2000-2017
for year_url in years_url:

    # For every page in the interval 1-4
    for page in pages:

        # Make a get request
        response = get('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=' + year_url +
        '&sort=num_votes,desc&page=' + page, headers = headers)

        # Pause the loop
        sleep(randint(8,15))

        # Monitor the requests
        requests += 1
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print('Request:{}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
        clear_output(wait = True)

        # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
        if response.status_code != 200:
            warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))

        # Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
        if requests > 72:
            warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')
            break

        # Parse the content of the request with BeautifulSoup
        page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Select all the 50 movie containers from a single page
        mv_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-advanced')

        # For every movie of these 50
        for container in mv_containers:
            # If the movie has a Metascore, then:
            if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None:

                # Scrape the name
                name = container.h3.a.text
                names.append(name)

                # Scrape the year
                year = container.h3.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
                years.append(year)

                # Scrape the IMDB rating
                imdb = float(container.strong.text)
                imdb_ratings.append(imdb)

                # Scrape the Metascore
                m_score = container.find('span', class_ = 'metascore').text
                metascores.append(int(m_score))

                # Scrape the number of votes
                vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
                votes.append(int(vote))
```

The requests keep running and won't stop. I'm doing this exactly as listed on this [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/) and I've been trying to figure what went wrong for hours.

Comment: Where's the loop?

Comment: Kindly provide whole code, not snippet of it

Comment: Include the import statements et. al. to give us reproducible code.

Comment: you are only breaking from the inner loop

Comment: Thanks @DrBwts, what would you suggest I do to break the entire loop?

Comment: its hard to say as I cant reproduce your code on my computer as its incomplete

Comment: @DrBwts alright thank you. I'll take another closer look, I can't seem to post the whole code here.

Comment: why not is there an issue with the text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a bool var when breaking from the inner loop. In outer loop you break if bool is true. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but I can't post my suggestion as a comment.

Comment: Hope the upvotes help to get you at fifty (being able to comment) I tried to do that yesterday and got 3 downvotes -_- because they claimed I should have been a comment but I wasn't repped 50 so the dude expected my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, good to see that i'm not the only one struggling. haha

Comment: yea the fastest way to get rep is trying to get the right answer/upvotes but find questions with bad grammar or such and then edit those it gets approved you'll get to 2 rep each time slow but easy lol